# Latest Ubuntu is lagging from previous one

Tags: drivers, partitioning

I have Dell Vostro laptop having 4 Gb Ram with pre-installed Ubuntu 16.04 in one partion and I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 from official iso as second partion. The Ubuntu 16.04 is working alright but with 20.04 there is some kind of slowness or freezing problem. I feel like there is some I/O driver missing in new system. Is there any way to find which set of drivers each system are running in order to find the problem.

Comment: The last release of Ubuntu is 21.04, or the 2021-April release and not 20.04 (which was 3 releases ago).  If you're talking a Desktop release (you didn't specify) the GNOME desktop is heavier thus the change to minimum specifications for 17.10 & up compared to 16.04.  Drivers are actually *kernel modules* and are thus linked to the kernel in use, LTS release have two stack options (you didn't specify any, if 16.04 was using GA or HWE, nor if using HWE or GA on 20.04) so full details may help.

Comment: It may be due to the RAM. Try Xubuntu instead. Xubuntu and Lubuntu consume a lot less memory than the regular Ubuntu desktop.

Answer (score 0):

System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab` to create some. Swap space must be contiguous. use `mkswap` or `fallocate`, not `dd`. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.